# Definition environment versus utf8

Tags: compiling, unicode, languages, input-encodings

I had some problems with my code, then I changed to

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and I could compile. But now I have another problem. I write in Brazilian portuguese, so the definition environment compiles in Portuguese, I mean, in the document we see "Definição" (Definition in portuguese).

So, when I try to compile, I have this message:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ção not set up for use with LaTeX
```

What can I do?

PS: I don'k know if it helps, but I use also these packages:

```
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Thanks :D

The minimal I could do hahaha:
The main file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}

\input{structure}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
  Um triângulo é um polígono de 3 lados.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

And the structure input file:

```
\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} % For including math equations, theorems, symbols, etc

\newtheorem{definitionT}{Definição}[section]

\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed} % Required for creating the theorem, definition, exercise and corollary boxes

% Theorem box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
backgroundcolor=black!5,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
innerbottommargin=5pt]{tBox}

\newenvironment{definition}{\begin{tBox}\begin{definitionT}}{\end{definitionT}\end{tBox}}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Please post a full minimal document we can test on our systems. Here we need to guess about the actual contents of your document. You might want to try loading fontenc before inputenc

Comment: There's a problema about that. I use a structure file to get some layout in my doc and there are a lot of code there... by the way, when I didn't use this file, and defined the defition environment in my main file, it worked! :/ If you want, I can send you the files by email.

Comment: You could try. But it is a good exercise to create minimal examples, both in terms of debugging experience (as you often end up finding the error) but also because the minimal example is such an important part of this site. Without it you are less likely to get help

Comment: It would be a good idea to create an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) from your custom style file, as you will isolate the problem quite quickly. Use the "binary search" method described in the link.

Comment: Make sure that your other file (the one which contains the word Definição) is utf8 encoded.

Comment: I just edited the question and created the mwe.

Comment: If I safe both files in `utf8` encoding, I can run your MWE without problem.

Comment: How do I do this, moewe? hahaha

Comment: @mvfs314 Well, it depends on your editor, I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/). In Notepad++ there is an entire menu dedicated to encoding. TeXworks has the file encoding in "preferences/editor". So step-by-step you would: 1) Find out how to convert the file to UTF8 with your preferred editor (google helps a lot). 2) Open the files and change the encoding. 3) Try compiling the document.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a file encoding issue solved in the comments.